# Alpha-numeric barcodes in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have created a barcode label printing app in vb. net using visual studio 2010. I have managed to successfully generate alpha-numeric numbers into the datagridview and the barcodes in the image column but instead of printing from 1A-1D, the barcode only prints the 1A when scanned. Please can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong, I’ve been trying to do this for the past few days, but nothing seems to work. Help much appreciated.

```
Dim alphaNumeric As String = String.Empty
        Dim number As String = txtSubNo.Text
        Dim alphabet As String = txtAlpha.Text
        Dim loopValue As String = txtNo..Text

        For index As Integer = 0 To loopValue - 1
            alphaNumeric = number.ToString & alphabet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
            DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "LAB No"
            DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "SUBNO"
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "INDICATOR"
            DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "BARCODE"
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtLabNo.Text, "" & alphaNumeric, Indicator.Text, PictureBox1.image)

            If Asc(alphabet) + 1 <= 90 Then
                alphabet = Chr(Asc(alphabet) + 1)
            Else
                alphabet = "A"

            End If

        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Since we cannot see any code or data or anything else, it's going to be very difficult to tell you anything useful. As per the [ask] guide please [edit] the question to provide a [mre] of your problem including sufficient code and data for someone to understand/reproduce the issue. See also the [tour] for more general guidance. Thanks.

Comment: How and where are you setting PictureBox1.image?

Comment: PictureBox1 is used to generate the barcode image. The issue is that the barcode is generated but not according to the alphanumeric values. Only the the first alphanumeric value is  generated and is populated onto the datagridview. If I have a alphanumeric of let’s say, 1A, 1B, 1C, the barcode that is generated are 3 of 1A only.

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing` within the loop looks suspicious to me. Doesn't that reset everything?